# Having problems installing pip, it says i don't have pip not recognized as external or internal command operable program or batch

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have windows 7, installed python 3.7 32 bit. I can run it. but if i go to the computer C:\ directory its not showing up. which is making it impossible to find it on the command prompt and installing pip.
when I open c:\program files> "dir" / p python is not shown.
when i open computer in windows it doesn't show python 3.7 in the c drive either.
but when i hit start all programs I can see python clear as day.
i can't install pip since i can't get my machine to find my python. help?

Comment: If you installed Python in the normal way, then you should be able to start a command shell (or PowerShell, if you prefer), and say `python -v` to see the Python version number.  If that works, then you can do `python -m pip install xxx` to install a module.

Comment: i must have done it a different way, i just used an installer i downloaded and it works. but yes i tried that. on my cmd it says both python and pip are not recognized as operable internal external bla bla bla.

Comment: that is why i  went and looked it up on the c drive and also looked it up on the cmd menu. nothing. but add remove programs shows python, and so does my start menu.

Comment: Odd.  I know people hate this suggestion, but I think you should uninstall and start over again.  The Windows installer should modify your path (if you let it).